# Reading and Editing text in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to open a text file, make changes to it and then update same file via Silverlight. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file through the file upload dialog. However, Silverlight does not allow writing to the disk (due to security reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378902/is-it-never-possible-to-get-the-fullname-from-a-file-using-silverlight-openfiledi/1378980#1378980)) except through the SaveFileDialog, so you will have to ask the user to save the file.