# Cannot get full path of a file in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, openfiledialog, fileinfo

I am working on a Web project, having Silverlight as the front end. I am opening a OpenFIleDialog in button click to get a file. I need to send the full path of the file to the server through service. I am trying dialog.File.FullName. But I am getting security exception. Is there any way to do this?

Regards,

Jawahar

Comment: a similar question was already posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378902/is-it-never-possible-to-get-the-fullname-from-a-file-using-silverlight-openfiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't getting the file path from the dialog box result and passing it as a string to the web service be sufficient?

Could you post your code for getting the file path from the Silverlight and the web service method you're calling?

Comment: But when accessing the FullName property of dialog.FileInfo, it just crashed. Security Exception,

Comment: are you just calling the openfiledialog or is it triggered by a user event?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of trust.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.95).aspx

> FullName: When called by **trusted applications**, gets the full path of the directory or file.

You need to look into setting up a Trusted Application [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or find another method for what you need to do.